# Два разных тире в одном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Из современной художественной литературы:

*Дружба – **не любовь, её свернуть труднее** – связующие нити торчат и лезут отовсюду, как в бракованных швейных изделиях, которые стали продавать в последние годы даже в дорогих магазинах.*

Здесь два тире на разных основаниях? Но это выглядит как вставная конструкция, неудачное оформление. А как тогда поставить знаки?

Comment: Начало конструкции уже даёт понять, что это не вставка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Дружба не любовь, её свернуть труднее: связующие нити торчат и лезут отовсюду, как в бракованных швейных изделиях, которые стали продавать в последние годы даже в дорогих магазинах.**

Объясняю почему. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым не ставится, если перед сказуемым стоит частица **НЕ** (Тире в таких случаях ставится, если сказуемое выражено инфинитивом).

Так что: *Дружба не любовь*.

А двоеточие я поставил потому, что вместо него можно поставить союз **ПОТОМУ ЧТО**.

Но, если часть после двоеточия не обозначает причину, а между частями можно поставить союз **А** или **НО**, то тире поставлено верно.

Или можно поставить точку с запятой, если эти две части предложения вообще никак между собой не связаны.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, ваш вариант оформления возможен (за это мой голос). Но дело в том, что автор у нас известный лауреат, книги переведены на разные языки, издательство очень приличное. Неужели корректор пропускает такие простые ошибки, он вообще-то знаком со справочником Розенталя))  Может, автору была важна именно такая пунктуация?

Comment: Тире ставится, если есть пауза! У Розенталя в пунктах об этом сказано.

Comment: oleedd, я могу с Вами согласиться по поводу первого тире, перед _не_. Но почему стоит второе, если, по правилам знаков препинания в БСП, нужно ставить двоеточие?

Comment: Максим, тире успешно заменяет двоеточие, если конструкция присоединительного характера (нет интонационного предупреждения с подчеркнутой паузой).

Comment: Точка с запятой не подходит, так как связь будет ослаблена, а это именно пояснительное присоединение.

Comment: Хорошо, Sharon, Вы тогда сами ответили на свой же вопрос по поводу второго тире. А по поводу первого уже сказано в комментартях. Ну а в своем ответе я указал свое мнение — как лучше оформить. Думаю, мы друг друга поняли

Comment: Все дело в том, что ставить одинаковые знаки (два тире) на разных основаниях вообще-то не рекомендуется, но иногда допускается. Но здесь это выглядит совсем не хорошо: оборот речи нераспространенный и воспринимается как единое целое. Решение автора мне не нравится, но другого решения я не вижу.  Вот и нет у меня пока ответа, я себе тоже не ответила.

Answer (score 1):

**Два тире в предложении**, поставленные на разных основаниях, мне не нравятся, но как быть? Ведь автор может поставить **интонационное тире** между подлежащим и именным сказуемым даже при наличии частицы НЕ, также вместо двоеточия можно использовать **присоединительное тире** для указания причины. Все это соответствует правилам.

Вероятно, решение может быть только **компромиссным.** Если бы вторая часть не была такой распространенной, то можно было бы поставить присоединительную  **запятую** вместо тире: Дружба – не любовь, её свернуть труднее, связующие нити торчат и лезут отовсюду, как в бракованных швейных изделиях.

Но в данном случае лучше разделить текст **на два предложения**:

***Дружба – не любовь, её свернуть труднее.** Связующие нити торчат и лезут отовсюду, как в бракованных швейных изделиях, которые стали продавать в последние годы даже в дорогих магазинах.*

P.S. Я принимаю предложенный ответ, так как он **был мне полезен.**